# Find common normals of the curves $y=1/x^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 - y = 0$

Tags: derivatives, conic-sections

Find common normals of the curves $y=1/x^2$  and $x^2 + y^2 - y = 0$

How we can find the point of contact of the curves because when I solve the both curve the I got irrational roots.

Comment: Who said there were common normals precisely  at an intersection point? And shouldn't you obtain points with irrational coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The second curve is the circle centred at $(0,\frac12)$, so its  normals are its diameters. Hence you have to find the normals to the first curve which pass through the centre of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.-The tangent at the point $\left(x_0,\dfrac{1}{x_0^2}\right)$ of the curve $y=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ 
has the equation $$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=-\frac{2}{x_0^3}$$ then the corresponding normal has equation
$$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=\frac{x_0^3}{2}$$This line must pass by the center $(0,\frac12)$ of the circle so you get the equation giving the possible values of $x_0$.